# Java lucene standard analyzer`s default delimiters?

Tags: java, lucene, delimiter

i am looking for all the delimiters on which java lucene standard analyzer tokenizes the input string.

need to know all delimiters that are by default used for tokenizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know (from Lucene in Action) that all characters which are not **a-zA-Z** or variatons of a-zA-Z that have **diacritics** are used as delimiters, including numbers. 

So you might have Mc'Donald splitted in "Mc" "Donald", you might have "Web2.0" tokenized as "Web", and so on.

The best is to do a test and enter all kinds of characters and then post your results here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it's SimpleAnalyzer what I've described. StandardAnalyzer is more complex: http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html